# How to handle time control in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, uidatepicker

Any idea on how to customize the UIDatePicker with single column with list of events in it,and user should be able to select one among it ? Let me know some details about it. or example related to it.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In code**:
UIDatePicker has the `datePickerMode` property exactly for this reason.
You can set it with `UIDatePickerModeTime`.

**In Interface Builder**:
The top property in Date Picker Attributes window is `Mode` - choose `Time`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these

`UIDatePickerModeDate`,           // Displays month, day, and year depending on the locale setting (e.g. November | 15 | 2007)

```
UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,    // Displays date, hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM)
```

Like this

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
```